# Cannot stream MP3 to firefox audio tag

Tags: c#, html, firefox, audio

I have a simple c# application that record & stream audio with naudio & lame. I use System.Net.Socket for the streaming, just wait for connection, read the header and then pass the socket to lame encoder that will send chunks of mp3.

Problem is, FF's audio tag cannot play the thing, it just returns 'All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.' And I specifically mention FF's audio tag because I can play it directly if I put the link in url tab. Searching, I found https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=502894#c1 that explain why firefox does all sort of random requests to determine file length and such. But I don't want that, is there anyway of making FF leaves my audio alone? (make it behaves as if I put the link in url tab)

Comment: I fixed the problem by including 'Cache-Control: no-cache' in response header to make FF stop requesting random stuff and just play the MP3 as I send it.